# MarkupBuilder using list

Tags: xml, groovy

I am currently using `sql.row("statement")` and storing to a list. I then am trying to setup my xml file using MarkupBuilder. Is there a better way than iterating over the list poping off an item and then parsing it to add my different column names and values?

What is stored by list entry is

```
ID='X' Period='Yearly' Lengh='test'
```

So the XML would be something similar to:

```
<table name='test'>
 <row>
  <column name=ID>X</column>
  <column name=Period>Yearly</column>
  <column name=Length>test</column>
 </row>
</table>
```

Comment: xstream is a great idea! I tried it out and I think that there is some disconnect between xstream and my list. The results were printing out weird.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your own object and use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) to serialize.  Example usage...

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
String xml = xstream.toXML(yourObject);
```